# Getting "global name 'foo' is not defined" with Python's timeit

Tags: python, scope, timeit

I'm trying to find out how much time it takes to execute a Python statement, so I looked online and found that the standard library provides a module called [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) that purports to do exactly that:

```
import timeit

def foo():
    # ... contains code I want to time ...

def dotime():
    t = timeit.Timer("foo()")
    time = t.timeit(1)
    print "took %fs\n" % (time,)

dotime()
```

However, this produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in dotime
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/timeit.py", line 193, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

I'm still new to Python and I don't fully understand all the scoping issues it has, but I don't know why this snippet doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Change this line:

```
t = timeit.Timer("foo()")
```

To this:

```
t = timeit.Timer("foo()", "from __main__ import foo")
```

Check out the link you provided at the very bottom.

> To give the timeit module access to functions you define, you can pass a setup parameter which contains an import statement:

I just tested it on my machine and it worked with the changes.

Comment: It works! However, this is a pretty stupid interface design if I have to both supply the command I wish to time as a string and to import the __main__ module for it to work.

Comment: Python namespacing is utter madness to me.  I assume that it makes sense to a certain sort of mind, but that sort of mind isn't one I happen to posess.  Thank $DEITY for Ruby, in my case.

Comment: womble, this is a wart, not a general python namespace problem.  Main thread:  http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/using-python-timeit-to-time-functions/  has links to other discussions about this.

Comment: @Gregg The link is no longer accessible (error 404). What was in that discussion?

Comment: ovgovolin:  looks fine to me!  http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/using-python-timeit-to-time-functions/ with links:  http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-November/412340.html  and http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-November/412341.html

Comment: ov, those were outdated.  now repaired:  http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-November/463664.html

Comment: @Gregg Thanks! Please, the next time put `@` before the name (`ovgolovin` or others) when reply. Otherwise the user is not notified (e.g. I wasn't notified when you made the replies in this thread).

Comment: those links are all dead

Comment: For Python 3, use the solution by @user2314737 `t = timeit.Timer("foo()", globals=globals())
`

Answer (score 46):

With Python 3, you can use `globals=globals()`

```
t = timeit.Timer("foo()", globals=globals())
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#examples):

> Another option is to pass `globals()` to the `globals` parameter, which
>   will cause the code to be executed within your current global
>   namespace. This can be more convenient than individually specifying
>   imports

Comment: Works for Python 3 only. `globals` not a parameter for Python 2's `timeit`

Comment: I had to merge `globals` and `locals` like this: `imports_and_vars=globals(); imports_and_vars.update(locals())`  then pass it like `t = timeit.Timer("foo()", globals=imports_and_vars)`

Answer (score 22):

You can try this hack:

```
import timeit

def foo():
    print 'bar'

def dotime():
    t = timeit.Timer("foo()")
    time = t.timeit(1)
    print "took %fs\n" % (time,)

import __builtin__
__builtin__.__dict__.update(locals())

dotime()
```

Comment: This hack is great if you'd otherwise need complex setup code.

Comment: Better than the startup code alternative given in other replies (i.e. better than `t = timeit.Timer("foo()", "from __main__ import foo")`). Specially if you want to test several different functions, it will save a lot of typing!

Comment: I've got about 20 imports, so passing them as an argument gets messy quick. This hack is awesome!

Comment: Great! On python3 however you need `import builtins` and 'builtins.__dict__.update(locals())'

Comment: Can you time multiple functions in the Time() function?

Answer (score 8):

```
t = timeit.Timer("foo()", "from __main__ import foo")
```

Since timeit doesn't have your stuff in scope.

Answer (score 0):

add into your setup "import thisfile; "

then when you call the setup function myfunc() use  "thisfile.myfunc()"

eg  "thisfile.py"

```
def myfunc():

 return 5

def testable(par):

 pass



t=timeit.timeit(stmt="testable(v)",setup="import thisfile; v=thisfile.myfunc();").repeat(10)

print( t )
```