# Python Timeit and “global name ... is not defined”

Tags: python, global-variables, timeit

I have a problem with timit function for code optimization. For example, I writing functions with parameters in a file, let's call it `myfunctions.py` containing :

```
def func1(X):
    Y = X+1
    return Y
```

and I test this function in a second file `test.py` where I call the timer function to test code performance (in obviously more complex problems!) containing :

```
import myfunctions
X0 = 1
t = Timer("Y0 = myfunctions.func1(X0)")
print Y0
print t.timeit()
```

The `Y0` is not calculated, and even if I comment `print Y0` line the error `global name 'myfunctions' is not defined` occured.

If I specify the setup with the command

```
t = Timer("Y0 = myfunctions.func1(X0)","import myfunctions")
```

now the error `global name 'X0' is not defined` occurred.

Is someone know how to solve this ? Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "global name 'foo' is not defined" with Python's timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551797/getting-global-name-foo-is-not-defined-with-pythons-timeit)

Answer (score 6):

You need `setup` parameter.  Try:

```
Timer("Y0 = myfunctions.func1(X0)", setup="import myfunctions; X0 = 1")
```

Comment: As I mentionned in the question, this return an error "global name 'X0' is not defined"

Comment: The global error have well disapeared. But this not create the Y0 value. Is there a solution for ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for `Y0` being undefined is that you have defined that in a string, but at parse time in the beginning of the execution the string is not evaluated yet to bring the variable into life. So put an `Y0 = 0` somewhere at the top of your script to have it defined beforehand.

All external functions and variables must be given to `Timer` using its `setup` argument. So you need `"import myfunctions; X0 = 1"` as the setup parameter.

This will work:

```
from timeit import Timer
import myfunctions
X0 = 1
Y0 = 0     #Have Y0 defined
t = Timer("Y0 = myfunctions.func1(X0)", "import myfunctions; X0 = %i" % (X0,))
print t.timeit()
print Y0
```

Look how I used `"X0 = %i" % (X0,)` to pass in the real value of the external X0 variable.

Another thing you might want to know is that if there are any functions in your main file that you want to use in `timeit`, you can make `timeit` recognize them by passing `from __main__ import *` as the second argument.

---

If you want `timeit` to be able to modify your variables, then you shouldn't pass strings to them. More conveniently you can pass callables to it. You should pass a callable that changes your desired variable. You don't need `setup` then. Look:

```
from timeit import Timer
import myfunctions

def measure_me():
    global Y0    #Make measure_me able to modify Y0
    Y0 = myfunctions.func1(X0)

X0 = 1
Y0 = 0     #Have Y0 defined
t = Timer(measure_me)
print t.timeit()
print Y0
```

As you see, I put `print Y0` **after** `print t.timeit()` since before execution you can't have its value changed!