# Timeit, NameError: global name is not defined. But I didn't use a global variable

Tags: python, global-variables, nameerror, timeit

I'd like to measure the execution speed of the following code:

```
def pe1():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:
            l.append(i)
    print sum(l)
```

I stored this code under pe1m.py .
Now I'd like to test the speed of file with the python interpreter. I did:

```
import timeit
import pe1m

t = timeit.Timer(stmt = 'pe1m.pe1()')
t.timeit()
```

but I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 195, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
NameError: global name 'pe1m' is not defined
```

But I don't have any global variables.

Comment: When you are importing the modules, there's a statement: import pe1m which, imho, is a typo for some other module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "global name 'foo' is not defined" with Python's timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551797/getting-global-name-foo-is-not-defined-with-pythons-timeit)

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
t = timeit.Timer(stmt='pe1()', setup='from pe1m import pe1')
```

`timeit.Timer` object doesn't know about the namespace you're calling it in so it can't access the `pe1m` module that you imported.

The `setup` argument is a statement executed in the context of the timed statement, they share the same namespace so whatever you define there, will be accessible in `stmt`.

Comment: Yes. You need a `setup` to import the module into the time namespace -- whether you use `from` or `pe1m.` is a matter or preference.

Comment: When I do `t = timeit.Timer(stmt='pe1()', setup='from pe1m import pe1')` then `t.timeit()` it just keeps on printing the output of `pe1m.pe1()`(which is 233168) infinitely.

Comment: @yak if you update your solution (add the `t.timeit(number=1)`  line), I can delete my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this

```
>>>def pe1():
>>>    l = []
>>>    for i in range(1000):
>>>        if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:
>>>            l.append(i)
>>>    print(sum(l))
>>>
>>>from  timeit import time it
>>>timeit('pe1()',setup="from __main__ import pe1",number=100) # Run 100 times
>>>timeit('pe1()',setup="from __main__ import pe1")  # run default times of 1000000
```