# Struggling with Python timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I'm struggling with the timeit function in Python, and, on a deeper level, I find myself very frustrated by the quirks of this function. I'm hoping I can get some help with both issues here.

I have a script (call it `my_script.py`) with a lot of different function definitions, and then a lot of other stuff being calculated below them all. I want to time only one of these functions in particular - let's call it `level_99_function(x)`. I have a big array stored in `my_input`. My first attempt:

```
timeit.timeit('f1(x)', setup = 'my_input')
```

Python returns the error: `NameError: global name 'angle' is not defined`.

Now my second attempt is to do the following:

```
print timeit.timeit('level_99_function(x)', setup = 'import numpy as np; import my_script.py; x= np.linspace(0,100)')
```

This doesn't generate any errors, but the problem is two-fold. First, and most importantly, it still doesn't time the `level_99_function` (or maybe it just doesn't print to output of the timer for whatever reason?) Second, the `import` statement seems to be running the entire script on import, which takes forever because of all the stuff I've got in this script aside from my `level_99_function`.

How do I get the timing of the function in question here? And on a more philosophical level, why is this such a struggle in Python? I've already got a variable and a function defined; all I want to do is time that function call with that variable. It would be nice to not have to write a super long line of code, or write multiple lines of code, or have to import things or any of that stuff. It's as easy as `tic` and `toc` in Matlab. I guess the corresponding Python commands would be to use 'time.clock()' before and after the function call, but I've read that this can be inaccurate and misleading.

Comment: _"the import statement seems to be running the entire script on import"_. Perhaps you need an [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard around all the non-function code in your module.

Comment: `timeit` is not equivalent to `tic...toc`. If you want the functionality of `tic...toc`, do something like: `start = time.clock(); my_function(); print time.clock() - start`

Comment: Re: your frustration: do yourself a favor and instead use iPython with its `%timeit` magic to benchmark your stuff. It is superior to vanilla `timeit` in a lot of ways.  For the rest, you will need to provide more code.  We can *guess*, but that's not what you came here for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "global name 'foo' is not defined" with Python's timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551797/getting-global-name-foo-is-not-defined-with-pythons-timeit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import numpy everytime within `setup`, instead you can import the function and variables you want from the current script with `from __main__ import ...` as shown in the example below.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def func1(x):
    pass

def func2(x):
    pass

def func3(x):
    return np.array(x > 1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.arange(10000)

    time = timeit.timeit('func3(x)', setup='from __main__ import func3, x', number=1000)
    print(time)
```

The [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) block will prevent the code within the `if` statement from being ran if you import the code from another script, meaning you won't accidentally run your timing tests if you import your functions.

This code only imports `func3` and `x`. I'm only interested in `func3` (not `func1` and `func2`) and I've defined a value to test with (I call it `x` but it's equivalent to your `my_input`). You don't need to import numpy in this case.

I would however completely and utterly advise you to take [roippi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247011/struggling-with-python-timeit#comment39333398_25247011) into consideration and use IPython. The `%timeit` magic method is very, very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. Definitely just going to use iPython's %timeit command.

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI for the future:

I recently submitted a patch against [issue2527](http://bugs.python.org/issue2527), which was [committed a few days ago](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/e0f681f4ade3) to the default branch.  So whenever 3.5 is publicly released, you can do this:

```
timeit.timeit('level_99_function(x)', globals=globals())
```

Not quite as awesome as iPython's `%timeit`, I know, but far better than the `from __main__ import ...` nonsense that you have to do right now.  [More info in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html#module-timeit).