# Python timeit NameError

Tags: python, import, nameerror, timeit

I want to use timeit in Python 3.5 to measure two functions. The first one relies on `import math` and the second one on `from math import log2`. I though I can handle this by passing the appropiate import statement as setup string when calling `timeit.repeat`. But I get `NameError: name 'math' is not defined`.
I don't want to pass the functions as their name strings. When the functions don't depend on imports, this code here works, but I need them with the calls of math.log2

Looking foward to your answers.

```
def spam_log_v1():
    for _ in range(1000):
        math.log2(2)


def spam_log_v2():
    for _ in range(1000):
        log2(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import timeit

    repeat = 3
    number = 1000
    unit = "usec"
    unittosec = {"usec": 1e6, "msec": 1000, "sec": 1}
    tests = [(spam_log_v1, 'import math'),
             (spam_log_v2, 'from math import log2')]

    for fct, setup in tests:
        res = timeit.repeat(fct, setup=setup, repeat=repeat, number=number)
        print("%s: %d loops, best of %d: %.3g %s per loop" %
              (fct.__name__, number, repeat,
               min(res) / number * unittosec[unit], unit))
```

Comment: Huh. Usually we see the opposite problem - `__main__` has the imports done, but the code being timed is in a scope created by `timeit` and can't see the imported things. Here, `timeit` does the imports, but functions from `__main__` can't see them.

Comment: Where is your `import math` line?

Comment: @boardrider: In a string in the `tests` list, where `spam_log_v1` can't see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "global name 'foo' is not defined" with Python's timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551797/getting-global-name-foo-is-not-defined-with-pythons-timeit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `inner` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/timeit.py#L71) which is run by `timeit.repeat` looks like this:

```
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0
```

where `{setup}` is replaced by the setup string and `{stmt}` is replaced by the statement string. Notice that the setup is run from inside `inner`. So if you place an import statement in `setup`, the module name becomes a *local variable* of `inner`. Later, when `spam_log_v1` is called from the `stmt`, the module name is not available to `spam_log_v1` since the module name is not in the global scope.

The fix is to simply import `math` and/or `from math import log2` at the global level of your script.

```
import math
from math import log2

def spam_log_v1():
    for _ in range(1000):
        math.log2(2)

def spam_log_v2():
    for _ in range(1000):
        log2(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    repeat = 3
    number = 1000
    unit = "usec"
    unittosec = {"usec": 1e6, "msec": 1000, "sec": 1}
    tests = [
        (spam_log_v1, ''),
        (spam_log_v2, '')]

    for fct, setup in tests:
        res = timeit.repeat(fct, setup=setup, repeat=repeat, number=number)
        print("%s: %d loops, best of %d: %.3g %s per loop" %
              (fct.__name__, number, repeat,
               min(res) / number * unittosec[unit], unit))
```